# Maybe a small issue detected in the Stack Overflow HTML editor related to adding hyperlinks

Tags: support, hyperlinks

[How can I merge two versions of a file in PHP or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935216/how-can-i-merge-two-versions-of-a-file-in-php-or-javascript/3935294#3935294)

I documented what I experienced as buggy behavior.  The site is so useful, I'm happy to help with a little QA. Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Update: Is the problem is that the second hyperlink I added didn't get numbered '2'?

Comment: Welcome to Meta SO, user152349/Gabriel! I see you edited your SO post to provide screenshots; please remove the screenshots from that post (since they're not relevant to the question) and add them here instead. Also, after your edit, I also no longer see the bug.

Comment: I'm ready to submit the screenshot to this post but I need 10 reputation points to have the ability to add an image...

Comment: `"http://Longest common subsequence problem"` is not a valid URL. I did edit your post though, I hope that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error looks to be because of your URL formatting. Which was a bad URL in the first place. This is the URL you have input for the first link.

```
http://Longest common subsequence problem
```

The syntax in the footer is a string for the URL without any spaces, and then an optional title text surrounding in quotation marks after a space. Nothing else allowed on the line. If a space is detected after the [URL](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), it is expecting the title text. When you just put in spaces without actually a title, it will break just like in your case.

---

[link text](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)

[1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com): http://Longest common subsequence problem

---

Now, because that footer isn't considered a link, further usage of the Hyperlink button will still start at 1. That's why your second link ended up being "1" (and why LCS also links to the same destination).

If you didn't have anything after the actual URL, or if everything afterwards is surrounded by [quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3935294/revisions), it doesn't matter where the position is. You can even link with [the same number](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) if you are actually trying to link to the same destination. Check out the source of my answer [over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/0081fe1e-80a9-43bf-ad3e-b7c164b97710/view-source).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.  It makes sense now.