# Hyperlink is shown incorrectly in SO post

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

In [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943255/more-about-rotateleft-method-in-java), the hyperlink is shown incorrectly in my browser (Firefox 3.6.10, WinXP SP3):

[image]

Interestingly enough, it is displayed correctly in the editor preview:

[image]

Comment: This will likely go down as `[status-bydesign]` because it's essentially malformed input.

Comment: If it is typed into the URL dialog, it should be escaped, so this should be considered a bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why it shows up properly in the preview, because it shouldn't: that URL is bad.

```
http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#rotateLeft(int, int)
```

It contains a space, and as [indicated in this recent report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67626/maybe-a-small-issue-detected-in-the-stack-overflow-html-editor-related-to-adding/67631#67631), it will cause the URL parser to treat the footer as normal text. In this scenario, though, the solution is to escape the space. And as noted in a few other questions [like here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses), the parentheses might need to be escaped as well; I'm not quite sure since the footer syntax doesn't use parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

While, as [Grace notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67765/hyperlink-is-shown-incorrectly-in-so-post/67767#67767) (no pun intended), the URL illegally contains a space and hence shouldn't display correctly, you're right in so far that it should look just as broken in the preview.

This will be the case after the next build.

Comment: Lies, that pun was totally intended.