# Links in answer editor appear correctly in preview, but not in the answer

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering, markdown-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hyperlink is shown incorrectly in SO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67765/hyperlink-is-shown-incorrectly-in-so-post)

I my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990105/date-formatter-is-not-formating-the-date-correctly/3990139#3990139) I attempt to link to a page in the Oracle Java documentation. The URL of the link is:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar(int, int, int)

When I try to make a link out of it using the markdown editor. [The link appears correctly in the preview, but malformed in the actual answer.][2]

Please help. Thanks!
  [2]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar(int, int, int)

Comment: This is the same issue as reported at [Hyperlink is shown incorrectly in SO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67765/hyperlink-is-shown-incorrectly-in-so-post). To summarize the answer, it's because of the spaces (and probably the parentheses as well) in your URL. You need to encode those, because the spaces are used to indicate title text when using that footer-based format.

Comment: That's fine, but it's still a bug, if you use the Hyperlink button on the editor it should encode the URL (with JavaScript encodeURI) for you. Also the preview should show you that it's not working.