# Link formatting works only in preview

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Links to URLs containing parentheses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses)
>   [Links in answer editor appear correctly in preview, but not in the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68242/links-in-answer-editor-appear-correctly-in-preview-but-not-in-the-answer)

I used the

```
[Link Text](http://actual-url.com)
```

link format in an answer and it showed correctly in preview:

---

[image]

---

But after I posted the answer it reverted to the unformated-ugly-version-which-makes-me-not-happy way of showing links as shown below.

[image]

*BTW: is it just me that wants to actually click on screenshot buttons even when knowing they're not real? and +1 for the nice circles please*

Comment: This is because of [parentheses in your URLs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses). If you encode them, they will work in both the preview *and* the real post. It's been [pointed out a](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68242/links-in-answer-editor-appear-correctly-in-preview-but-not-in-the-answer) [couple times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67765/hyperlink-is-shown-incorrectly-in-so-post) that these URLs with parentheses incorrectly render correctly on preview.

Comment: We have to close as a duplicate, but I want to point out that this is an excellent illustration of the bug.